# cmake: multiple CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY

Tags: cmake, package

I am using Cmake with Cpack to create linux packages. I install my executable in /bin/MyProgram; in order to work properly, the executable needs to have access to an external file (an xml schema). I would like Cpack to generate a package that will install that file in a specific location (e.g. /usr/share/MyProgram) other than the one where the executable is stored.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use INSTALL(FILES ) like this:

```
install(FILES files... DESTINATION <dir>
      [PERMISSIONS permissions...]
      [CONFIGURATIONS [Debug|Release|...]]
      [COMPONENT <component>]
      [RENAME <name>] [OPTIONAL])
```

You can read more about the INSTALL command in the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainstall).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use COMPONENT for this.

```
install(
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Assets
    DESTINATION "Library/Application Support/${PROJECT_NAME}/"
    COMPONENT ASSETS
)

set(CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL OFF)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL ASSETS)
```